# Discord.js random message after x amount of time (Code Correction)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I need to have my discord bot send a random message every 1.5 hours (1 second here for testing) and so far I used the following code but it did not work:

```
'use strict';


const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');


const client = new Client();



client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in to Discord succesfully as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});


  var facts = ['Zebra', 'Elephant', 'Goose', 'Lion', 'Turtle', 'Mongoose']
  setInterval(function() {
  var fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length)
  console.log(facts[fact]) 
  }, 1000) // Changed to 1s for testing


client.on('message', message => {

  if (message.content != '101') {
    message.channel.send(facts[fact]);
  }
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Comment: You aren't sending a message every x time here. Your code just assigning a random fact to a variable for every 1 sec and send it back whenever a user chat something other than 101

Comment: "But it did not work" is not enough information. *What* isn't working specifically? Have you attempted to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to catch the fetch you're sending the message to

```js
//I'll use .get but discord.js says .fetch should work
let Channel = client.channels.get("Channel ID");
```

Then we'll pick an item from the array

```js
let demo = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let Picked = demo[Math.floor(Math.random() * demo.length)]);
```

Then we'll put the setTimeout

```js
setTimeout( () => {
    let demo = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
    let Picked = demo[Math.floor(Math.random() * demo.length)]);
    //I already explained the above part
    Channel.send(Picked)
        .then( msg => {
            //If you wanna do anything like adding reactions
        }
},1000);
```

Comment: It is still not working for me- some syntax errors?